# Prove that there is no holomorphic map $s: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ with $p \circ s = \operatorname{id}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, projective-geometry, projective-space

> Let $p:\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the natural projection. Prove that there is no holomorphic map $s: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ with $p \circ s = \operatorname{id}$.

I'm seeking for intuition for the problem. I started to think about what the map $s$ would  have to be in order for this to hold and for example if $s([z_0:\dots:z_n]) = (z_0,\dots,z_n)$, the the map would give the identity, but this $s$ isn't even well-defined  let alone holomorphic since $[z_0:\dots:z_n]=[\lambda z_0:\dots:\lambda z_n]$ for any non-zero $\lambda$, but clearly $(z_0,\dots,z_n) \ne (\lambda z_0,\dots, \lambda z_n) $ unless $\lambda = 1$.

Now my understanding of the projective space is very limited so I don't have any intuition as to why such map wouldn't exist and I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light in to why this shouldn't be true?

Comment: Do you have knowledge of algebraic topology/homological algebra? If so, you could show that the existence of such a map (which would be an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ would have to induce an isomorphism on homology groups (or fundamental groups, based on your knowledge)), from which you could derive a contradiction. It is a quick way of proving this, though admittedly not the most elementary one

Comment: I have enough to see that this would be quite a nice solution, but I would be happy to get more intuition for the projective space rather than use the machinery from algebraic topology. Thanks for the nice idea though! @Azur

Comment: Recall that the only holomorphic maps $\Bbb P^n\to \Bbb C$ are constants.

Comment: @TedShifrin So $p \circ z_j : \Bbb P^n\to \Bbb C$ is constant for each of the coordinate functions $z_j$. Will this automatically imply that $s$ is itself constant also?

Comment: You mean $z_j\circ s$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. @TedShifrin

Comment: @NathanielJohonson An example of what such a map $s$ might look like.  The function $s([z_0: \cdots : z_n]) = (1, z_1/z_0, \cdots z_n/z_0)$ almost works, and perhaps gives a sense of why such an $s$ can't exist.

Comment: So would $p \circ s$ be in this case $[1: \dots :z_n]$? I don’t think I see the issue with this map. @DavidGoldberg

Comment: $p \circ s = [z_0 : \cdots : z_n]$ so is the identity map.  The problem is that $s$ isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{P}^n$, because it's not defined at $[0, 1, \cdots, 1]$. @NathanielJohonson

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact, $s(\mathbb{P}^n)$ is compact and thus closed and bounded.  But that means there is a $p \in \mathbb{P}^n$ with $|s(p)|$ maximized.  Pick an unitary matrix $M$ that takes $s(p)$ to $(a, 0, \ldots 0)$ where $a = |s(p)|$.  Then for $g = Ms$, $|g|$ is also maximized at $p$, but now $g(p) = (a, 0, .., 0)$.  This is clearly not maximal if $g_1$ is non-constant since $g_1$ would then be an open mapping.  But if $g_1$ is constant, then this $|g(p)|$ can only be maximal if all the $g_i$ are constant, but then $s$ would be constant, contradicting $p \circ s = \mbox{id}$.

Comment: Oh right, that's much simpler.